# Control points on a curve node with drivers?

Tags: node-editor, interface, drivers

I want to control a point on a curve within an [RGB curves node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/color/rgb_curves.html) with a driver. Is there any way to get the RNA path for it's X and Y fields?

Comment: @batFINGER I see you edited the question for clarification, but probably the OP meant the cycles RGB curves node, not the compositor one.

Comment: Possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/is-there-a-way-of-keyframing-rgb-curves